# using Default system Keypad and recreating only Keypad necessary

Tags: tabwidget, keypad

I have a requirement to create a Keypad as follows
1) only Edit Text is Visible Initially
2) on click of the Edit Text launches a tabwidget/Buttons/ImageView  and the first tab of the Widget contains the Default system keypad and rest of the tabs contain the Custom Keypad.
3) The EditText appears on top of the Keypad and the tabWi
I tried using the SCrollView as mentioned below
I have the following XML

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true">

      <EditText
      android:id="@+id/editview"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
      android:ems="10"
      android:inputType="text"/>

    </ScrollView>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-8dip ">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="-8dip" 
            android:layout_marginLeft="-8dip" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/button1"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="-8dip" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/button2"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="-8dip" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/button3"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="-8dip" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This way it launches the Keypad and the Image View is visible at the bottom of screen
by setting android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustResize|adjustPan"

But i want to get only ImageView and the Keypad on click of EditText & Edit Text should be on top of the Keypad.

Comment: Found a Solution to the Problem just setpadding ( 0 ,0,0,height) on the parent layout